# Extract feature from featurecollection in MongoDB atlas

Tags: python, atlas, folium, mongodb

I need to extract data from my database and add pointer to the map with folium.

```
import folium
import os
from folium import features
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 1000

lons = +5 - np.random.normal(size=N)
lats = 48 - np.random.normal(size=N)

data = {
   'type': 'FeatureCollection',
   'features': [
      {
         'type': 'Feature',
         'geometry': {
            'type': 'MultiPoint',
            'coordinates': [[lon, lat] for (lat, lon) in zip(lats, lons)],
         },
         'properties': {'prop0': 'value0'}
      },
   ],
}
m = folium.Map([17.3616, 78.4747], zoom_start = 10)
m.add_child(features.GeoJson(data))
m.save('Features.html')
```

Comment: Your code works and adds points to the map. They're all located in France, but you zoom the map to India. I don't see any attempt to connect to a database.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/mongodbatlas https://pypi.org/project/atlasapi/